# Carregar uma lista de Enums

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um `selectOneMenu` assim:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="diminui" value="#{naturemb.nature.diminui}" effect="clip">
 <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{naturemb.carregarAtributos()}" itemValue="#{naturemb.carregarAtributos()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Quero exibir na tela os valores do meu Enum:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

public enum Atributos {

    HP("HP"), ATTACK("Attack"), DEFENSE("Defense"), SPECIAL_ATTACK("Sp. Attack"), SPECIAL_DEFENSE("Sp. Defense"), SPEED(
            "Speed");

    private String nome;

    private Atributos(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Criei um método no Controller assim:

```
public String carregarAtributos() {
        List<Atributos> lista = Arrays.asList(Atributos.values());
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            return lista.get(i).getNome();
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Mas não está funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Aqui vai uma dica. Use o enhanced-for: `for (Atributos a : Atributos.values()) { return lista.getNome(); }`

Comment: @VictorStafusa qual a diferença  e vantagem?

Comment: Douglas, com isso você não precisar ficar usando um `int` a toda hora para indexar e achar o elemento, deixando assim o código bem mais simples. Além disso, para alguns tipos de lista (listas ligadas), o método `get(int)` é relativamente lento, mas com essa forma de iteração, você o evita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude seu método para:

```
public List<String> carregarAtributos() {
        List<Atributos> lista = Arrays.asList(Atributos.values());
        List<String> retorno = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
           retorno.add(lista.get(i).getNome());
        }
        return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você já tem um Enum, pode usar ele sem criar uma lista de String. É melhor pois facilita o reuso. No seu exemplo, basta fazer:

```
public List<Atributos> carregarAtributos() {
   return Arrays.asList(Atributos.values());
}
```

E no selectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="diminui" value="#{naturemb.nature.diminui}" effect="clip">
   <f:selectItems var="atributo" itemLabel="#{atributo.nome}" itemValue="#{atributo}" value="#{naturemb.carregarAtributos()}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Obs. 1: como vc vai usar o Enum em vez da string, tem que mudar o tipo para Enum tb na variável de destino.

Obs. 2: acho que não é necessário colocar um `setNome` no enum pois vc não vai conseguir mudar o valor em tempo de execução, somente na criação (em `Atributos(String nome)`).

Answer (score 1):

Douglas,

A maneira mais fácil de retornar a lista de enums é:

```
public EnumSet<Atributos> listarAtributos() {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Atributos.class);
}
```

Espero que ajude ;)

Abraço!